# how can i call objects in a row using vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am a vuejs newbie and i am having difficulties trying to make my objects return back in a row they are in a column.

components/sellingItems.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container class="my-5">
    <v-row>
        <v-col
        sm="6"
        md="4"
        >
          <v-card outlined>
            <v-img :src="image" height="200px" />
            <v-card-title> {{ name}} </v-card-title>
            <v-card-subtitle> ${{ price }}</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-actions>
                          <v-btn @click="addToCart" color="success" outlined >
                              <v-icon small left> add </v-icon>
                              Add to Cart
                          </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: ['id', 'image', 'name', 'price'],
  
}
</script>

pages/index.vue
```

After adding the for loop my products list turns into a column, i prefer it in a row to suit my aim

The Index Page [image: sample]

Stack overflow wont let me post the index page code so heres a screenshot
[image: Index Page Code]

Comment: where is the for loop?

Comment: "SO won't let me post text code so here is a screenshot"?? Whaat do you mean? It's the opposite, don't post code images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thew problem seems to be that you are creating a new row vor every item

```html
<template>
  <v-container class="my-5">
    <v-row> <!-- <=== here is your row -->
      <v-col sm="6" md="4">
          ... etc
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

you can either move the `<v-row>` into the parent component and wrap `<SellingItems v-for...>` or pass an array (`products`) into the component and have the `v-for` within that component

```html
<SellingItems :items="products" ... >
```

```html
<template>
  <v-container class="my-5">
    <v-row> 
      <v-col sm="6" md="4" v-for="item in items"> <!-- <=== move v-for here -->
          ... etc
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check this**

use a row and columns by editing your class to determine how many items per row I have added code in codepen

https://codepen.io/Juan-Carlos-MA/pen/yLMdLRX?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <br>
    <br>
      <v-slider
        v-model="fruits"
        :tick-labels="ticksLabels"
        :max="3"
        step="1"
        ticks="always"
        tick-size="4"
      ></v-slider>
    <div class="row">
      <div v-for="item in items" :class="selection">
        <v-card :loading="loading" class="mx-auto my-12" max-width="374">
          <template slot="progress">
            <v-progress-linear color="deep-purple" height="10" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
          </template>

          <v-img height="250" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/cooking.png"></v-img>

          <v-card-title>{{ item.mensaje }}</v-card-title>
          <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>

          <v-card-title>{{ item.precio }}</v-card-title>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn color="deep-purple lighten-2" text @click="reserve">
              Add TO CART
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    loading: false,
    selection: "col-6",
    value: 0,
    fruits: 1,
    ticksLabels: ["one", "two", "tree", "four"],
    items: [
      { mensaje: "Tamales", precio: "$300" },
      { mensaje: "Atole", precio: "$300" },
      { mensaje: "Taquito", precio: "$300" },
      { mensaje: "Taquito", precio: "$300" }
    ]
  }),

  methods: {
    reserve() {
      this.loading = true;
      setTimeout(() => (this.loading = false), 2000);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    fruits: function (val) {
      console.log(val);
      if (val == 0) {
        this.selection = "col-12";
      } else {
        if (val == 1) {
          this.selection = "col-6";
        } else {
          if (val == 2) {
            this.selection = "col-4";
          } else {
            if (val == 3) {
              this.selection = "col-3";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add code blocks in the same answer instead of links.